Rename a column from a GridDb TimeSeries without loosing data
I want to be able to rename a column from a GridDb TimeSeries while preserving the data in the column.
Context
Assuming the following TimeSeries Wind: [Date, speed, diretction] containing the following rows:
Wind[date='Thu Aug 29 23:37:15 CEST 2024', speed=25, diretction=80]

How can i rename the diretction column as direction?
What i've tried
The only way I’ve found is to iterate over the column of the schema and replace the one with the wrong name with a new one.
It does replace the column name, but i loose all the data that were in the previous one. It actually acts as a delete column followed by add columns
public static void renameColumn(GridStore store) throws GSException {
    ContainerInfo conInfo = store.getContainerInfo("wind");

    var newColumnList = IntStream.range(0, conInfo.getColumnCount())
            .mapToObj(conInfo::getColumnInfo)
            .map(col -> col.getName().equals("diretction")
                    ? new ColumnInfo("direction", col.getType())
                    : col
            ).toList();

    conInfo.setColumnInfoList(newColumnList);
    store.putTimeSeries("wind", conInfo, true);
}

